# How to set set the Connection property of the SqlCommand object when hit with an "ExecuteNonQuery" error?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I have been reading here on several questions that I shouldn't use AddWithValue so I tried to change my code and I get this error "'ExecuteNonQuery: Connection property has not been initialized.'" and according the the posts here I have to set the Connection property of the SqlCommand object but in my case how do I do that? I tried several "Using(sqlCommand... " etc and nothing seem to work. Any ideas?

```
 protected void txtSignup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (isformvalid()) 
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings ["MyShoppingBD"].ConnectionString))

            
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into tblUsers(Username,Password,Name,Email,Usertype) Values('" + txtUserName.Text + "','" + txtPassw.Text + "','" + txtFullName.Text + "','" + txtEmail.Text + "', 'User' )");
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Clear();
                sqlCon.Close();

                Response.Write("<script>alert('Registration Successfully done!');</script>");
                lblMsg.Visible = true;
                lblMsg.Text = "Registration Successfully done";
                lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;

            }
        Response.Redirect("~/SignIn.aspx");            
    }
```

I use this code in web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name ="MyShoppingBD" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=MyEShoppingDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Look at the second parameter you can pass to the `SqlCommand` constructor. Then *please* go and read up about using parameters with SQL. Your code is currently vulnerable to SQL Injection.

Comment: You don't need to `.Close()` your connection since it's in a `using`

Comment: SqlCommand has a constructor that you can give the connection besides the command string. Or simply use the Connection Property of SqlCommand to setthe Connection.

Comment: Does it work if you write directly your connection string within the constructor?

Comment: Just use the [SqlCommand(String, SqlConnection)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand__ctor_System_String_System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_)  constructor

Comment: i addded  sqlCmd.Connection = sqlCon; under the sql command code and now it works. Thank you i'll remove close too!

Comment: Please consider following the "use parametrized queries" advice you were already given.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use

```
SqlCommand cmd = sqlCon.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "...";
```

or

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("...", sqlCon);
```

And just a reminder as with nearly any question regarding SQL queries: You should not add your values to the query by string concatenation but use parameterized queries to prevent SQL Injection. This will also get rid of various conversion issues, when using `.ToString()` to add a value to the query (for instance with `double` values).

```cs
string query = "insert into tblUsers(Username,Password,Name,Email,Usertype) values (@username, @password, @email, @usertype)";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, sqlCon);
    
var unp= new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.NVarchar);
unp.Value = theUsername;
cmd.Parameters.Add(unp);

//or simpler, thanks to @Cleptus' comment
cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.NVarchar).Value = thePassword;

//add other parameters accordingly

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: As a personal preference, I like to use the overload that [returns the SqlParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_SqlDbType_). `var unp = cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarchar);` and then `unp.Value = theUsername;`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the recommend to dump and not use AddWithValue? Well, that does NOT mean you toss out the concept, the use, and the time honored advice to use parameters!

I suggest this code:

```
string strSQL = "INSERT INTO tblUsers (Username, Password, Name, Email, UserType) " 
              + "VALUES (@UserName,@Password,@Name,@Email, @UserType)"

using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL,
   new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("MyShoppingBD").ConnectionString)))
{
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtUserName.Text;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Password", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtPassw.Text;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtFullName.Text;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = txtEmail.Text;
    cmdSQL.Parameters.Add("@UserType", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = "User";


    cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
    cmdSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Now there is a truckload of things in above.

First up, as I am typing in the parameters, I can "see" the SQL statement. So, I don't have to think or remember the parm values - they can be seen in the code editor. In other words, I don't actually have to "hold" in my human mark 101 memory cache pre-fetch carbon based memory unit!

While the parms is a few more lines of code, after I typed in the first line, then I whacked ctrl-d 5 times.

Now, I not typing, but just editing the text after the @ sign. So downarrow, edit, downarrow edit. It almost like editing values in a Excel sheet. Once you done this a few times, you not go back to big long ugly strings.

So While this gets us a "nice" set of parameters?

Well, I think BETTER was I actually did LESS typing in the editor, but MORE important is I don't have that long string concat - it is REALLY hard to read, hard to write, hard to maintain. And REALLY easy to break or mess up!

So as much as the value of using parameters? I think the value of avoiding that long string is VERY nice, and it is VERY difficult to deal with.

And if a user types in for Full name say John O'Mally? Well, now  you have a quote in that string and it will VERY easy blow up on you.

And often most miss the fact that the sql cmd object has BOTH parameters object, and a connection object for you.

So no need to create a separate connection object - the cmd object has one for you! And this is REALLY nice when wanting to pass sql to another "general" routine - pass a cmd object instead. The connection object and the parameters collection AND the sql string ALL go along for the ride! (3 in one!!).

So all fits in one cute little object for you!

So while the parameters is a real must do? I think the elimination of the long concentatation with single and double quotes? - a real bear to deal with.

And better yet with parameters?
Be it date, datetime, numbers, strings? You don't have to worry about quoting the data (or not in the case of numbers). So strong type conversion occurs for you, and without effort.